# Lucky Dip Program

Tags: c#

I was trying to make a lucky dip program where 6 random numbers,1-59, are chosen then printed out in an array. I managed to get this to work, however you needed to use an IndexOf method so that no same number was printed twice by checking if the new number is already in the array.

```
using System;


namespace LuckyDip
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] luckyNumbers = new int[6];
            Random random = new Random();

            for (int x = 0; x<6; x++)
            {
                 num[x] = random.Next(1,59);
                 Console.WriteLine(num[x]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        } 
    }
}
```

It prints out numbers, but sometimes they are the same.

Comment: Your solution is in your question, what problems did you have with indexOf?

Comment: You could alter your algorithm a little bit: Have an array of 1-59, shuffle it, take first 6 elements, print them.

Answer (score 0):

You state that you want to use `IndexOf`, but that method is used for strings ([see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=net-5.0)). Your example has an int array so the solution below uses `Contains`. This solution adds a check within your loop and generates a new number if this number already exists within your array. If you really need to use `IndexOf`, create a string array and convert the numbers using `String.valueOf(randomNumber)`

```
using System;           
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         int[] luckyNumbers = new int[6];
         Random random = new Random();

         for (int x = 0; x<6; x++)
         {
             int randomNumber = random.Next(1,59);
             while (luckyNumbers.Contains(randomNumber))
             {
                randomNumber = random.Next(1,59);
             }
             luckyNumbers[x] = randomNumber;
             Console.WriteLine(luckyNumbers[x]);

         }
     } 
}
```

Another possible solution would be:

```
using System;                   
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        int arraySize = 6;
        int[] luckyNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1,59).OrderBy(g => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(arraySize).ToArray();
    
        for (int x = 0; x < luckyNumbers.Length; x++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(luckyNumbers[x]);
        }
    }
}
```